# Permanent delete shortcut in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I sometime need to delete the `node_modules` folder. But it's too slow on windows, and I always have to delete them again from the bin and was wondering what the shortcut for this action was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the file you want to delete and use `shift` and `delete`.

[image]